# Bluetooth chipset high voltage

Tags: smart-home, bluetooth

I understand we usually use relay to do controlled switch, but I'm wondering if the Bluetooth protocol could work on high voltage I mean 110-220v.
So is it theoretically possible to design a Bluetooth chipset running directly on such voltage?
If yes what are the cons not to do it ? From my little knowledge, I guess it's mainly consumption problems.

Hope I'm clear enough; thanks for any input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot do that. Thinking of Bluetooth as a quite complex protocol of approximately 1k pages of documentation the power electronics to build such circuit would be overly sized.

Think of your PC, it inputs 110 or 220 and still there is the power unit that lowers the voltage to low DC as in every micro circuit you see nowadays.

Comment: This is the wrong answer. All digital electronics use some form of supply regulation, you could build that into a chipset (but it would be stupid, and limit your logic library).

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is yes. Power line voltage of 110-220 VAC needs to be step down to a lower DC voltage such as 5VDC or 3.3VDC depending to overall device power requirement. Most Bluetooth module require a 5VDC or 3.3VDC to operate. The device will have a microcontroller, a Bluetooth module and some type of control circuitry to controlling an external device such as a switch.

HTH

Comment: Hum, it kindly answer my question it's not possible to design a Bluetooth chipset which will be directly powered by a 110-240VAC power line.

Comment: @MatthieuDucorps My answer is one such way of achieving your goal